# moodle: SQL where clause from stdclass object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, moodle

Im using moodle and function get_course_students to get a list of students

```php
$students = get_course_students($course->id, 'lastname'); 
echo print_r($students);
```

This outputs:

```
Array (
  [4382] => stdClass Object (
    [confirmed] => 1 
  , [username] => test22 
  , [firstname] => test 
  , [lastname] => 22 
  , [maildisplay] => 2 
  , [mailformat] => 1 
  , [maildigest] => 0 
  , [email] => test22@test.couk 
  , [city] => test 
  , [country] => GB 
  , [picture] => 1 
  , [idnumber] => 
  , [department] => 
  , [institution] => 
  , [emailstop] => 0 
  , [lang] => en_utf8 
  , [timezone] => 99 
  , [lastaccess] => 
  , [id] => 4382 )
  [518] => stdClass Object (
  , [confirmed] => 1 
  , [username] => st999999 
  , [firstname] => st999999 
  , [lastname] => account 
  , [maildisplay] => 2 
  , [mailformat] => 1 
  , [maildigest] => 0 
  , [email] => st999999@test.co.uk 
  , [city] => 
  , [country] => GB 
  , [picture] => 1 
  , [idnumber] => 
  , [department] => 
  , [institution] => 
  , [emailstop] => 0 
  , [lang] => en_utf8 
  , [timezone] => 99 
  , [lastaccess] => 1315843176 
  , [id] => 518
  )
)
```

I then want to count the amount of records in a table but only the students that are currently assigned to the course.

```
$totalreportscountrecords = count_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mdl_ilp_reports WHERE course = $course->id AND user = $students");
```

How do i modify the SQL statement to do this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the SQL behind the function `get_course_students()`?

Comment: http://xref.moodle.org/nav.html?_functions/index.html

Comment: Can't you just use `count_course_students()`?

Comment: that will count the students on the course, i want to count the records in mdl_ilp_reports WHERE course = $course->id AND ((user = 555) OR (user = 556) OR (user = 556 )) the user ids will be taken from the get_course_students function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using a custom table. I couldn't find a table names *_reports in Moodle-1.9 or Moodle-2.0.

However, here is a possible solution:

if get_course_students give you the userids, then you can use

```
WHERE course = $course->id AND user IN (555,556)
```

You can use PHP's implode to get a comma separated list of userids, provided the get_course_students return an array of values.

Hope this helps.